# Bootstrap Angular navbar issues

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Newby to Angular and Bootstrap. Running Angular 11, Bootstrap 5.

Following [Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/)

The navbar rendered but the dropdown actions do not work. Following a [Adding Bootstrap](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/angular-11-add-bootstrap-exampleexample.html)

Noticed bootstrap install pulled 4.5.3?

Installing bootstrap and jquery

```
$ npm install bootstrap --save
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ bootstrap@4.5.3
updated 1 package and audited 1471 packages in 8.777s

84 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities


$ npm install jquery --save
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.3 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ jquery@3.5.1
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 1470 packages in 5.587s

83 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities


bruce@COBAR-DT MINGW64 /d/apps/angular/GCA-NG (master)
$ npm install popper.js --save
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ popper.js@1.16.1
added 1 package from 2 contributors and audited 1471 packages in 5.647s

84 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

angular.json

```
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

menu.component.html
Checked id on anchor and ui arial-labelledby=

```
               <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" routerLink="/welcome">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a  id="aboutGcaMnuLnk" role="button"
                            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"
                            class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">
                            About GCA
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="aboutGcaMnuLnk">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Leadership</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our History</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Map of GCA</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a  id="docMnuLnk" role="button"
                            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"
                            class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">
                           Documents
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="docMnuLnk">
                            <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Board Meetings</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Board Meeting Agenda</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Board Meeting Minutes</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: afaik you dont need jQuery for Bootstrap5

Comment: @afaik I thought not specifying version on the install would pull V5. However, it pulled 4.5.3. I have no clue if I can specify 5.0 and overlay it and whether 4.5.3 is dependent on jquery?

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibility of mismatch between IDs of the target or data-bs-toggle="dropdown" attribute of dropdown.
this snippet is from documentation:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown link
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I added the menu html and verified the anchor id matches ul aria-labelledby. The script or whatever doesn't fire and the dropdown doesn't work.

Comment: @BRandall do one thing: copy-paste this navbar code from official documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar
if it works your dependencies are correctly imported. that's an option out then